# What should I learn to code a bot in Telegram?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-api

I want to code and creat a bot for telegram that does these things:

1 - shows a massage to the person that hit start button

2 - then it gets a name as an input

3 - then again shows a massage

4 - getting an input

5 - at the end add the inputs to a defualt text and showing it;

for exampele:

-start

+Hi What is your name?

-X

+How old are you?

-Y

+Your name is X and you are Y years old.

My second Question is that how can I Connect to bots together, for example imagine I want to pass some input from this bot to make a poll(voting massage), in order to do that I should send the name to let's say @vote, how is that possible and what should I learn to do such things with my bot?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First you're gonna have to explore telegram bot API documentation [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/).

Then you should choose your programming language and the library you want to use.

There are different libraries for each language, I'm gonna name a few:

- Go: https://github.com/aliforever/go-telegram-bot-api (DISCLAIMER: I wrote and maintain it)
- Python: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI
- NodeJS: https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf

I'm gonna give you an example for what you want in python using `pyTelegramBotAPI`:

First install the library using pip:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI.git
```

Then run this script:

```py
import telebot

API_TOKEN = 'PLACE_BOT_TOKEN_HERE'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)

user_info = {}


def set_user_state(user_id, state):
    if user_id not in user_info:
        user_info[user_id] = {}

    user_info[user_id]["state"] = state


def get_user_state(user_id):
    if user_id in user_info:
        if "state" in user_info[user_id]:
            return user_info[user_id]["state"]
    return "Welcome"


def set_user_info(user_id, name=None, age=None):
    if name is None and age is None:
        return
    if name is not None:
        user_info[user_id]["name"] = name
    if age is not None:
        user_info[user_id]["age"] = age


def get_user_info(user_id):
    return user_info[user_id]


@bot.message_handler()
def echo_all(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id

    if message.text == "/start":
        bot.reply_to(message, "Hi What is your name?")
        set_user_state(user_id, "EnterName")
        return

    user_state = get_user_state(user_id)

    if user_state == "EnterName":
        set_user_info(user_id, name=message.text)
        bot.reply_to(message, "How old are you?")
        set_user_state(user_id, "EnterAge")
        return
    if user_state == "EnterAge":
        set_user_info(user_id, age=message.text)
        info = get_user_info(user_id)
        bot.reply_to(message, "Your name is %s and you are %s years old." %(info["name"], info["age"]))
        set_user_state(user_id, "Welcome")
        return
    bot.reply_to(message, "To restart please send /start")


bot.infinity_polling()
```

Here we use a dictionary to place user state and info, you can place them anywhere like databases or json files.

Then we update a user's state based on their interactions with the bot.

---

For your second question, bots cannot communicate with each other so you should look for other solutions. In the case of your question where you want to create a poll, you should check [sendPoll](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#sendpoll) method as well as [PollAnswer](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#pollanswer) object which you receive when a user votes in a poll.